# Google cloud HTTP load balancer always returns unhealthy instance for meteor app

Tags: meteor, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I am trying to set up a HTTP load balancer for my Meteor app on google cloud. I have the application set up correctly, and I know this because I can visit the IP given in the Network Load Balancer.

However, when I try and set up a HTTP load balancer, the health checks always say that the instances are unhealthy (even though I know they are not). I tried including a route in my application that returns a status 200, and pointing the health check towards that route.

Here is exactly what I did, step by step:

1. Create new instance template/group for the app.
2. Upload image to google cloud.
3. Create replication controller and service for the app.
4. The network load balancer was created automatically. Additionally, there were two firewall rules allowing HTTP/HTTPS traffic on all IPs.

Then I try and create the HTTP load balancer. I create a backend service in the load balancer with all the VMs corresponding to the meteor app. Then I create a new global forwarding rule. No matter what, the instances are labelled "unhealthy" and the IP from the global forwarding rule returns a "Server Error".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use HTTP load balancing on Google Cloud with Kubernetes, you have to take a slightly different approach than for network load balancing, due to the current lack of built-in support for HTTP balancing.

I suspect you created your service in step 3 with `type: LoadBalancer`. This won't work properly because of how the LoadBalancer type is implemented, which causes the service to be available only on the network forwarding rule's IP address, rather than on each host's IP address.

What will work, however, is using `type: NodePort`, which will cause the service to be reachable on the automatically-chosen node port on each host's external IP address. This plays more nicely with the HTTP load balancer. You can then pass this node port to the HTTP load balancer that you create. Once you open up a firewall on the node port, you should be good to go!

If you want more concrete steps, a [walkthrough of how to use HTTP load balancers](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) with Container Engine was actually recently added to GKE's documentation. The same steps should work with normal Kubernetes.

As a final note, now that version 1.0 is out the door, the team is getting back to adding some missing features, including native support for L7 load balancing. We hope to make it much easier for you soon!

Comment: To add HTTPS, could I do the following?

1) create global forwarding rule with HTTPS and the certificates
2) use the same backend service as the HTTP global forwarding rule

Comment: Will this setup be able to support websockets? I am running a "chat service" on kubernetes and I did the following: (1) set up chat service with NodePort, (2) get the nodePort the chat service is exposed on and create firewall rule/load balancer for that.

Comment: It looks like HTTP/HTTPS load balancing does not currently support websockets: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/

Comment: However, the normal network load balancer that comes up when you set `type: LoadBalancer` DOES support websockets if you also set `sessionAffinity: ClientIP` https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/services.md#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies

Comment: To get back to your first question, I'm not too familiar with the HTTPS load balancing, but my understanding is that it should work.

Comment: Ok, it appears that I can't use websockets with HTTPS load balancing. With long polling, sticky sessions are required (I'm using socket.io). I tried setting the 'sessionAffinity` key to `ClientIP` in the service config, but that didn't seem to solve the sticky-session problem. Is there extra configuration needed in Kubernetes to get sticky-sessions when the service is a NodePort?

Comment: For websockets/sticky sessions, you'll want to switch back to `type: LoadBalancer` and just use the network load balancing. That's because with network load balancing we can configure its session affinity to ensure the requests from the same IP all arrive at the same node, which can then ensure that they all are routed to the same pod. When using NodePort with HTTP load balancing, we can't configure the HTTP load balancer's affinity.

Comment: Ah, ok. Is there any way to set up HTTPS with a network load balancer?

Comment: I guess I could use the LoadBalancer type and put it in front of Cloudflare to use its SSL abilities

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the network load balancer can't handle your certs for you. You could have your application handle terminating the SSL, but I'm not sure how much work that would be for your particular app.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant ? The linked example (https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) does not relate to healthchecks… or am i missing something ? And it actually explains the opposite on the very first phrase "Google Container Engine offers integrated support for network load balancing with the type: LoadBalancer field in your service configuration file." I'm quite lost in this lb/healthiness, thx if any clarification provided